# Change CiviCRM Event notification emails

Tags: civievent, email

When participants register for events/trainings, notifications are sent automatically to a pre-specified email. How can I change so the notifications come to different email addresses? Newbie using CiviCRM 4.6

Answer (score 3):

In the event settings under 'Online Registration' you will see a section for 'Confirmation Email'.  If you select this CiviCRM will send a confirmation email to the participant.  You can also send a copy (CC or BCC) to another email address.

[image: Confirmation Email settings]

See the user guide for more information: [Registration confirmation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/events/online-event-registration/#registration-confirmation)

Comment: Hi William, thank you so much for responding to my query. It seems that actually we have a universal email that's been set-up through the creation of a profile which is then included on a particular event template that's being used. So even though the send confirmation email button on the section that you've highlighted above was set to 'no' in our case, emails were still being sent to an old email address. Hopefully changing the profile email will be the fix we need!

Comment: @Holly I'm glad you've managed to sort this out.  If this works, you should post this as an answer in case anyone else has the same problem in future.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out we have a universal email that's been set-up through the creation of a profile which is then included on a particular event template that's being used. So even though the send confirmation email button on the 'online registration' page was set to 'no' in our case, emails were still being sent to an old email address. Changing the profile email address that's used in the template has solved this issue.